# How to add saved search in amp file?

Tags: alfresco

I have saves some searches in alfresco, now I want to add these saved searches in AMP file. Anyone know how to do this?

When we save any search new xml file is generated at `Company Home>>Data Dictionary>>Saved Searches`

Where we need to store this file in amp file?

what change need to do in `model-context.xml`?

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: I think you need an ACP rather than an AMP - ACP is the usual way of packaging up content (AMP is for code/config). Why do you think you need an AMP instead?

Comment: Agreed, you need an ACP. But Yogesh might be trying to package everything up--customizations plus some data (in this case, saved searches), so to do that, he'll need to create an ACP to capture the Saved Searches, then set that ACP up as bootstrap data for the AMP.